# Why are Pex cinch clamps breaking?

Tags: plumbing

I used Pex cinch clamps on my baseboard hot water heating and system. The system is about 7 years old. I have had 2 different clamps break and the water dripped on my floor. Are the cinch clamps the type to use or should they all be changed out for the copper compression type? I’m thinking the expansion of the SS clamp is different than the fitting causing them to split.

Comment: Post a picture of one of your clamps - and what tool did you use to crimp them? It's possible they were crimped too tight if you didn't use the standard tool, which may have weakened the metal.

Comment: The cinch clamps are often problematic for DIYers to do right, use the copper rings instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have had those rings break on me also.  The adjustment of the tool has to be just right.  I don't use them anymore.  I would use the copper compression ring.